# Selenide and Firefox record faulty screenshot

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenide

I'm using Selenide and Phantomjs to test a Webapplication.
Im taking the Screenshot as follows:

```
byte[] bytes = ((TakesScreenshot)webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
returnImage = ImageIO.read(bis);
```

For input Elements, however, the screenshot looks like this:[faulty screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZ3c.png)

It actually looks like this (when using chrome/firefox) 
[how it's supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2ZuA.png)

The interesting thing is, that when I set Selenide to use phantomjs (Configuration.Browser = "phantomjs") it takes the screenshots correctly.
It only occurs on that kind of element, too. Buttons etc are being recorded fine. Any ideas?

PS: The screenshots attached to this post are cropped, the code here takes screenshots of the entire page. In my code, I crop the screenshot only to the desired element but even on the screenshot displaying the entire screen the element is not recorded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can take screenshot a element using below code:-

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("hplogo"));

// Get entire page screenshot
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);

// Get the location of element on the page
Point point = ele.getLocation();

// Get width and height of the element
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();

// Crop the entire page screenshot to get only element screenshot
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),
    eleWidth, eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", screenshot);

// Copy the element screenshot to disk
File screenshotLocation = new File("C:\\images\\GoogleLogo_screenshot.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, screenshotLocation);
```

Now in above code you are getting the getWidth() and getHeight(). You can try to adjust it by adding or subtracting the value.

Comment: I am afraid that this is not an answer to my question. I dont have problems taking the screenshot, its the element thats not displayed correctly.

Comment: Oh so your driver is self not showing proper element when invoked?

Comment: The screenshot doesnt show the element properly. For some reasing it now works, I have no clue why. Thanks anyways !